# Processing Django Migrations

Tags: django

We have a multiple database Django project that uses database routers.

For some reason when we run a migration the reference to the migration end up in the django_migrations table but no actual migrations are actually run - that is - there is no change in target database.

Following is the database router for the `elegant` database.

```py
class ElegantRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    elegant application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read elegant models go to elegant.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'elegant':
            return 'elegant'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write elegant models go to elegant.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'elegant':
            return 'elegant'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the elegant app is involved.
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'elegant' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'elegant':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the elegant app only appears in the 'elegant'
        database.
        """
        print('allow_migrate',app_label,db)
        if app_label == 'elegant':
            return db == 'elegant'
        return None
```

Following is the DATABASES settings for the project.

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'depot_maestro': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_filemaker_pyodbc',
        'HOST': os.getenv('FILEMAKER_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.getenv('FILEMAKER_PORT'),
        'USER': os.getenv('FILEMAKER_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.getenv('FILEMAKER_PASSWORD'),
        'NAME': os.getenv('FILEMAKER_FILENAME'),
        'OPTIONS' : {
            'driver' : os.getenv('FILEMAKER_DRIVER'),
            'driver_supports_utf8' : True,
            'autocommit' : True ,
        },
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': os.getenv('FILEMAKER_FILENAME'),
            'SERIALIZE': False,
        }
    },
    'postgres': {
            'NAME': os.getenv('POSTGRES_DATABASE'),
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'USER': os.getenv('POSTGRES_USER'),
            'PASSWORD': os.getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD')
    },
    'elegant': {
            'NAME': os.getenv('ELEGANT_DATABASE'),
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'USER': os.getenv('ELEGANT_USER'),
            'PASSWORD': os.getenv('ELEGANT_PASSWORD')
    },
}
```

**Update**

Using `sqlmigrate` for the project with database routers returns no sql.

```
./manage.py sqlmigrate elegant 0057 --database elegant
BEGIN;
--
-- Remove field internal_id from organisationelegant
--
--
-- Add field uuid to organisationelegant
--
--
-- Alter field id on organisationelegant
--
COMMIT;
```

where as the project without database routers returns SQL

```
./manage.py sqlmigrate elegant 0057
BEGIN;
--
-- Remove field internal_id from organisationelegant
--
ALTER TABLE "organisation" DROP COLUMN "id" CASCADE;
...
--
-- Alter field id on organisationelegant
--
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS "organisation_uuid_19796862_like";
COMMIT;
```

How can you make a migration with database routers take effect when allow migrate already returns true and the migration files are being produced ?

Comment: How do routers look like, do they allow_migrate

Comment: @iklinac All but one of the routers allow_migrate.

Comment: It still feels a bit confusing to me, all migrations or just migrations that are related to the elegant app are not present?,This is expected for all other databases other than database named elegant in DATABASES. Could you show your DATABASES example config

Comment: @iklinac It's confusing to me as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new project with the same app referencing the same database and migrated from that project.

**Update**

I added symbolic links to the main project.